# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre usar el metodo save() en un Model y en un ModelForm en Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Qué diferencia existe entre:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

y

```
class PersonForm(models.ModelForm):
    ...
    def save(self, commit=True):
        ...
```

¿Cómo se comporta el método save en los dos casos? y ¿cuando es necesario usar cada uno de ellos?

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634287/whats-the-difference-between-django-modelform-and-models-model

Comment: Gracias por comentar @DiegoAvila pero me refería a alterar el método save() en especifico, y como funciona dentro de un model y un modelForm

Comment: class PersonForm(models.ModelForm) ????  qué es eso ? Te refieres a  forms.ModelForm ?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día:

El `save(....)` de de `models.Model` : [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods)

El `save()` de `forms.ModelForm` devuelve las instancias que se han guardado en la base de datos. Si los datos de una instancia dada no cambiaron en los datos enlazados, la instancia no se guardará en la base de datos y no se incluirá en el valor de retorno. ando faltan campos en el formulario (por ejemplo, porque se han excluido), el campo no establecerá estos campos save(). Puede encontrar más información sobre esta restricción, que también es válida en forma regular ModelForms, en Selección de los campos a usar.